# Essence of Time

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems, quantum-gravity

When I tried to derive General relativity I realized that in different non-inertial frames we just can't compare anything, including time intervals, because gravity spoils everything thus making everything uncomparable. So we just can't construct an ideal clock.

We can't measure anything, because in a non-inertial frame thing are under other conditions, in another state. The space-time itself is modified.

But maybe there is something that is not affected by gravity?

Comment: Are you asking this from a mathematical or a physical perspective?

Comment: Near a black hole atomic clocks will crush like shit.

Comment: *we just can't compare anything* Many physical quantities are different for different observers but some are the same.

Answer (score 1):

An ideal clock in GR is one that exactly measures proper time. We may not be able to get truly ideal clocks, but within their operational limits, existing atomic clocks are reasonable approximations for most purposes.

Comment: But it's not mathematically reasonable. From a mathematician's point of view it's as if we didn't measure at all.

Comment: Sorry, I don’t know what mathematicians would or would not consider reasonable. I can only tell you that physicists consider it reasonable

Comment: Einstein's theory has nothing to do with phisics. It's just a Riemann geometry that happened to give numerically right results. Einstein himself didn't know what time is.

Comment: "[area of mathematics] that happens to give numerically right results" describes literally everything in theoretical physics.

Comment: @MaratRamazanov your comment on "Einstein's theory has nothing to do with physics...." witnesses a complete misunderstanding about what Physics is. One does not get good results as compared with experiments by chance. Physics uses Math. However the difficult part is setting the interpretation rules of the mathematical objects. That is definitely Physics.

Comment: In the twin's paradox the young twin was a little  crushed during his journey, jet-lagged, nauseated. So we can't truly compare them, it is no pure experiment and you just can't do it right.

Comment: @MaratRamazanov You could in principal "do" the twin paradox experiment (it is of course not an actual paradox).

Comment: @MaratRamazanov said “Einstein's theory has nothing to do with phisics”. I think you would be hard pressed to find any professional physicist today that would agree with that statement, particularly given its successes in describing nature.